# How to set font style for text in Captcha generated by jCaptcha

Tags: java, captcha

I am generating a captcha image using jcaptcha-all-1.0-RC6.

The code snippet for the same is below

```
          captchaService = new DefaultManageableImageCaptchaService();
          logger.info(" After creating instance  getCaptcha ");
          long id = System.currentTimeMillis();
          String captchaId = String.valueOf(id);

          logger.info(" getCaptcha Id " + captchaId);

          logger.info("***********Coming into captcha service***************************************************");
          BufferedImage challenge = captchaService
                       .getImageChallengeForID(captchaId);
          WritableRaster raster = challenge.getRaster();
        ColorModel model = challenge.getColorModel();
          challenge.setRGB(0,25,51);

          logger.debug("challenge:" + challenge);
          ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

          ImageIO.write(challenge, "jpeg", outputStream);

          outputStream.close();
          outputStream.flush();
          byte[] res = outputStream.toByteArray();

          String encodedImage = Base64.encodeBase64String(res);
```

However the image quality that I am getting is not of great quality. Is there something we can do to get a better image quality with better readability.

Even changing font style can be useful. Any help on that would also be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your Image by configuration, you have to extend ListImageCaptchaEngine and use Generator :

- Word Generator
- Color Generator
- Background Generator
- Font Generator

  ```
  public class MyImageCaptchaEngine extends ListImageCaptchaEngine {

  @Override
  protected void buildInitialFactories() {

      WordGenerator wgen = new RandomWordGenerator("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789");
      RandomRangeColorGenerator cgen = new RandomRangeColorGenerator(new int[] { 0, 255 }, new int[] { 20, 100 }, new int[] { 20, 100 });

      TextPaster textPaster = new RandomTextPaster(new Integer(4), new Integer(5), cgen, Boolean.TRUE);

      BackgroundGenerator backgroundGenerator = new UniColorBackgroundGenerator(new Integer(240), new Integer(50), new Color(252,252,253));


      Font[] fontsList = new Font[] { new Font("Helvetica", Font.TYPE1_FONT, 10), new Font("Arial", 0, 14), new Font("Vardana", 0, 17), };

      FontGenerator fontGenerator = new RandomFontGenerator(new Integer(18), new Integer(30), fontsList);
      WordToImage wordToImage = new ComposedWordToImage(fontGenerator, backgroundGenerator, textPaster);
          this.addFactory(new GimpyFactory(wgen, wordToImage));
      }
  }
  ```

And to use it

```
ImageCaptchaService instance = new DefaultManageableImageCaptchaService(
            new FastHashMapCaptchaStore(),
            new MyImageCaptchaEngine(),
            180,
            100000,
            75000);
```

Comment: Can you help me on how to declare backgroundGenerator, textPaster, wgen that is specified in your code.

Comment: I have used your code. However now I am getting error like word is too tall: try to use less letter, smaller font or bigger background. Please help on this

Comment: @ParthaBisoi just play around with the settings, i.e. image size, font size etc. and see which would work for you. You could make the letters smaller but then they might not be readable, you could make the image bigger which might not fit your ui design, you might use shorter words which might contradict your security requirements etc. - it's up to you to find the exact settings that work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`DefaultGimpyEngine`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.livesense/org.liveSense.service.captcha/1.0.3/org/liveSense/service/captcha/DefaultGimpyEngine.java) on how to extend `ListImageCaptchaEngine` and provide settings like background color, image size, fonts etc. (you could copy that and provide your own values).

AFAIK font style is actually a different font of the same family (say "Arial bold" and "Arial regular" are 2 styles of the "Arial" family). Thus you could only select the fonts you want (make sure they're available on the system).

Comment: It would help if you can explain with a sample code.

Comment: @ParthaBisoi have a look at the source I linked. You might want to dig further into the code and documentation to understand what's happening there. Explaining all that would be out of scope for SO.